# How to show the errors in test cases with unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a test case. How can I realize which test case was failed? Should I write some functions for this as well? When i run my code it just show the error, but without the exact function (at Pycharm).

```
import unittest
from buddy_pair import buddy

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_buddy_pair(self):
        pair = buddy(48, 50)
        self.assertEqual(pair, [48, 75])

    def test_buddy_pair2(self):
        pair = buddy(10, 50)
        self.assertEqual(pair, [48, 75])

    def test_buddy_None(self):
        pair = buddy(1000, 500)
        self.assertEqual(pair, 2)

    def test_buddy_another_pair(self):
        pair = buddy(100, 5000)
        self.assertEqual(pair, [140, 195])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: If you run that file, *it tells you which (if any) failed*. Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html.

Comment: PyCharm *also* lists the names of the methods, showing which passed and failed, as shown in e.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/testing-your-first-python-application.html#run-test-automatically.